# Possible to disable search-as-you-type?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I have a large log file open (larger than one "screenful", let's say 100,000 lines), and Press Ctrl/Cmd+F to search, it begins to search immediately as-I-type.

It is "work" to find the right spot in a large log file to work on. It is frustrating to lose that spot because finding it causes me to do that work again. Let's say that spot is around line 50,000 in our example.

When I am in line 50,000 and expect my search result to be the next occurrence of "Monkey", as I type "monkey" into the search box, it begins to search the whole file, immediately, for "M" then "Mon" (depending on how fast I type, there's a lag).

So far so good, however if I make the slightest typo, let's say I type "Mom" it will start the search from the beginning of the file, and find "Mommy" or whatever matches the typo. In short: I should have the freedom to "craft" my search phrase, especially when regex is involved, without frantically jumping all over the file while I am correcting my search. There should be a search mode that allows me to click "Search" when I am ready, and not a moment sooner.

Due to the jumping-as-I-type, I lose my carefully-crafted position around line 50,000 and am lost in a sea of log lines, irrelevant to what I was actually looking for.

Question: Can the search-as-you-type be disabled with a setting?

If it can't be disabled, is there a "traditional" find & replace dialog that I am not aware of and have never seen? One that acts only when I click "Next" or "Search" or "Replace" but not before I have completely composed by search phrase / regex? Is there a plugin (couldn't find one)?

I am aware of the workaround of searching only in the selection but with large files (> 100k lines) VS Code gets extremely slow and acts funky; it's not very easy or smooth to select the rest of the file and creates again the problem of finding the beginning of the selection.

Another workaround is to split the screen so I have two copies of the file open, one with my desired cursor position, and the other just as an experimental playground to get my search phrase right.

Of course I don't want to do additional work like split the large files into smaller ones via posix commands; not always are those available and it's infinitely more mental and time-consuming work to do that before a quick inspection of a large log file, than to begrudgingly deal with the search-as-you-type as it is.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `Editor > Find: Cursor Move on Type`  and there is a search one as well.

Comment: You are a life saver!! If you write this as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!